# PCIe device communication in Linux/PCIe driver

Tags: driver, embedded-linux, pci-e

I would need to connect to a Frame Grabber card (that itself connects to a camera through a camera link interface), with a FPGA that runs some image processing application, connected to my computer board through PCIe interface, to get images and some image processing data. The computer board is running Linux and a c++ onboard software.

As I have never worked with PCIe interface, I searched through internet for a linux driver to use, but I did not find any. Should I write the driver myself or is there an API or readily-available driver to use? If I should write the driver myself, is there a guideline/tutorial to help that you would recommend for a beginner?

Thanks alot for helping and sharing your experience!

Comment: Possibly you will need a custom driver. For FPGA in general there is a framework, though I never looked at.